# How can I use jQuery events and effects and DOM in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In my project specifcation, I was assigned to do a full website and the last part of it is confusing.

d) Use JQuery to make it much easier to use JavaScript on your website. Add the hide/show of the panel and other JQuery events and effects such as fade in/out, slide up/down.

e) Use one of the most important properties of jQuery that comes with a bunch of DOM related methods that make it easy to access and manipulate elements and attributes.

How would I be able to implement parts d and e in my code? what are examples of these events especially DOM methods. and can I implement these in a drop down list? here's a sample code.

```
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

I haven't tried anything much, I keep searching in w3schools but its no help.

Comment: "*comes with a bunch*" - ah, nice professional business requirements there ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well... to start with your question is a bit ambiguous, if I understand correctly you have no idea what JQuery is about. You can find that out on their official website at [JQuery](https://jquery.com)

JQuery is... simply put a simpler way to write JavaScript, it has some stuff called methods and what they do is help you write a small amount of code in place of many lines of JavaScript codes that produce the exact same result.

**Let's use this part of your code to solve your problem d)**

```js
$('.dropbtn').click(function() {
  // $('.dropdown-content').show(); // Shows your dropdown menu
  // $('.dropdown-content').hide(); // Hides your dropdown menu
  $('.dropdown-content').toggle(); // Hides/Shows your dropdown menu (inverts the state of visibility)
});
```

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- This line brings in JQuery into your application via CDN -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Now, the e) problem**
This must be talking about the **$** operator used in the code sample it greatly reduces the amount of work required to access DOM (Document Object Model) elements in JavaScript

Comment: To me, it looks like (e) is talking about jquery collections, eg `$(".dropdown-content > a").click(function() { alert("You chose: " + $(this).text()); return false; })` to apply events / effects to multiple elements without needing a loop.

Comment: I believe @freedomn is right about the solution to problem e) in the question. Reading the question again it makes more sense if this is the solution